# TypeError: App.check_stru() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

Olá

Eu estou a tentar criar uma app em python

Este é o codigo

```
#IMPORTS

import os as os

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config_path = os.path.join("config")
        self.account_path = os.path.join("account")
        self.desktop_path = os.path.join("account/desktop")
        self.book_shelf_path = os.path.join("account/desktop/books_shelf")
        self.storage_books = os.path.join("config/storage")
    def check_stru(self):
        self.was_created = 0
        self.already_created = 0
        if not os.path.exists(self.config_path):
            os.mkdir(self.config_path)
            print("1 created")
            self.was_created += 1
        else:
            self.already_created += 1
        if not os.path.exists(self.account_path):
            os.mkdir(self.account_path)
            print("2 created")
            self.was_created += 1
        else:
            self.already_created += 1
        if not os.path.exists(self.desktop_path):
            os.mkdir(self.desktop_path)
            print("3 created")
            self.was_created += 1
        else:
            self.already_created += 1
        if not os.path.exists(self.book_shelf_path):
            os.mkdir(self.book_shelf_path)
            print("4 created")
            self.was_created += 1
        else:
            self.already_created += 1
        if not os.path.exists(self.storage_books):
            os.mkdir(self.storage_books)
            print("5 created")
            self.was_created += 1
        else:
            self.already_created += 1


run = App

run.check_stru()
```

Mas não sei muito bem mas dá o seguinte erro:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "none\src\main.py", line 48, in <module>
    run.check_stru()
TypeError: App.check_stru() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Podem me ajudar? Eu sou um bocado novo na parte do self e nas classes...

Obrigado

Comment: Deveria ser `run = App()` (com parênteses). Sem os parênteses vc está fazendo com que `run` receba a própria classe `App`, já com parênteses vc está criando uma instância de `App`, que acho que é o que vc quer fazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Devilas. Tudo bem?

Faltou acrescentar um parênteses nesta linha:

```
run = App
```

Ela deveria ficar assim:

```
run = App()
```

Por que isso? No primeiro caso, você está dizendo que `run` é igual a classe `App` e não a um objeto que é instância da classe `App`. Já no segundo caso, há o instanciamento. Você deve fazer o instanciamento com parênteses mesmo que a construção da classe não exija argumentos, o que é o caso da classe que você está utilizando.

Testei aqui e obtive isso na saída:

```
1 created
2 created
3 created
4 created
5 created
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).